# How can I get the redirected URL to scrape with HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, html-agility-pack

I made a class that uses HtmlAgilityPack to get the content of a view hosted by my app, but when I have redirections (HTTP 302), the Load() method, doesn't follow them.
(The app uses Windows Authentication, can't leave anonymous access enabled).

At first, I had the following code:

```
        string lUrl = "http://server/Controler/View/ID";
        var lAuth = new NetworkCredential("Username", "Password", "NTDomain");
        var lProxy = new WebProxy() { Credentials = lAuth };
        var lWeb = new HtmlWeb
        {
            PreRequest = delegate (HttpWebRequest webRequest)
            {
                webRequest.Timeout = 1200000;
                return true;
            }
        };

        var lPage = lWeb.Load(lUrl, "GET", lProxy, lAuth);
```

Digging around to figure it out, I tried to fetch the final URL with WebRequest.GetResponse(), but I kept getting HTTP 401 exceptions.

```
        HttpWebRequest lRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(lUrl);
        lRequest.Credentials = lAuth;
        lRequest.Proxy = lProxy;
        lRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
        WebResponse lResponse = lRequest.GetResponse(); // Throws 401

        var lWeb = new HtmlWeb
        {
            PreRequest = delegate (HttpWebRequest webRequest)
            {
                webRequest.Timeout = 1200000;
                return true;
            }
        };

        var lPage = lWeb.Load(lUrl, "GET", lProxy, lAuth);
```

However, if I run the GetResponse() method in a try block, then I can still get the final URL from lRequest.Address.AbsoluteUri
IE:

```
        HttpWebRequest lRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(lUrl);
        lRequest.Credentials = lAuth;
        lRequest.Proxy = lProxy;
        lRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
        try
        {
            WebResponse lResponse = lRequest.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (WebException) { }

        var lWeb = new HtmlWeb
        {
            PreRequest = delegate (HttpWebRequest webRequest)
            {
                webRequest.Timeout = 1200000;
                return true;
            }
        };

        var lPage = lWeb.Load(lUrl, "GET", lProxy, lAuth);

        lUrl = lRequest.Address.AbsoluteUri; // Works!? lUrl == "http://server/OtherControler/View/ID" ...
```

It works, if GetResponse throws an exception, lRequest still gets updated, but it seems weird to me, and HttpWebRequest is apparently becoming obsolete (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest) so is there another way to get the right destination URL? Or maybe something needs to be changed on the IIS server?

Comment: According to your description, I couldn't understand your issue clearly. Could you please tell me what you mean about the 302 redirect? Do you mean you use HtmlAgilityPack to scap the 302 redirect page?

Comment: No, I don't want the redirect page itself, if I pass `http://some.url/page?abcd` to the Load() method and the server redirects to `http://other.url/page?abcd`, I want to fetch the content of `http://other.url/page?abcd`.